# translate CodeIgniter query into normal mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How can I translate this function written in CodeIgniter into a normal MySQL query?

```
public function getUserAttend ( $User_ID , $Date_From , $Date_To )
{
    $this -> db -> select 
            ( ''
            . '(select attend_permission_confirmed from ts_permission pr  where pr.attend_in_attend_id = att.attend_id LIMIT 1 ) as attend_permission_confirmed_out '
            . ',(select attend_permission_confirmed from ts_permission pr  where pr.attend_out_attend_id = att.attend_id   LIMIT 1 ) as attend_permission_confirmed_in '
            . ',`attend_id`, `attend_date`, `attend_user`, `attend_time_in`, `attend_time_out`, `attend_ctime_in`, `attend_ctime_out`, `attend_notes_in`, `attend_notes_out`, `attend_modifiedby`, `attend_checkoutip`'
            . ', `attend_official_in`, `attend_official_out`, `attend_morning_permission` '
            , FALSE );

    $this -> db -> order_by ( 'attend_id' , 'ASC' );
    $res = $this -> db -> get_where ( "ts_attendance as att" , array (
        "attend_user" => $User_ID ,
        "attend_date >= " => $Date_From ,
        "attend_date < " => $Date_To
            )
    );

    return $res -> result_array ();
}
```

Note that I have no expertise with the Php CodeIgniter framework.
Can you explain what this code represents in mySQL?

Comment: I'd prefer to start with the data and the desired result. see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Codeigniters built-in function `last_query()`

```
$qstring= $this->db->last_query();
```

more information [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html):